# Is there any way to format converted docx file to text in php?

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, .doc

Hello I want to format in a nice way the converted doc or docx file to text in php?
The code below is the class that I used to convert docx file to text.

```
class DocxConversion{
    private $filename;

    public function __construct($filePath) {
        $this->filename = $filePath;
    }

    private function read_doc() {
        $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
        $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
        $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
        $outtext = "";
        foreach($lines as $thisline)
          {
            $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
            if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
              {
              } else {
                $outtext .= $thisline." ";
              }
          }
         $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
        return $outtext;
    }

    private function read_docx(){

        $striped_content = '';
        $content = '';

        $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

        if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }// end while

        zip_close($zip);

        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
        $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

        return $striped_content;
    }

 /************************excel sheet************************************/

function xlsx_to_text($input_file){
    $xml_filename = "xl/sharedStrings.xml"; //content file name
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive;
    $output_text = "";
    if(true === $zip_handle->open($input_file)){
        if(($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName($xml_filename)) !== false){
            $xml_datas = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);
            $xml_handle = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_datas, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $output_text = strip_tags($xml_handle->saveXML());
        }else{
            $output_text .="";
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }else{
    $output_text .="";
    }
    return $output_text;
}

/*************************power point files*****************************/
function pptx_to_text($input_file){
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive;
    $output_text = "";
    if(true === $zip_handle->open($input_file)){
        $slide_number = 1; //loop through slide files
        while(($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName("ppt/slides/slide".$slide_number.".xml")) !== false){
            $xml_datas = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);
            $xml_handle = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_datas, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $output_text .= strip_tags($xml_handle->saveXML());
            $slide_number++;
        }
        if($slide_number == 1){
            $output_text .="";
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }else{
    $output_text .="";
    }
    return $output_text;
}


    public function convertToText() {

        if(isset($this->filename) && !file_exists($this->filename)) {
            return "File Not exists";
        }

        $fileArray = pathinfo($this->filename);
        $file_ext  = $fileArray['extension'];
        if($file_ext == "doc" || $file_ext == "docx" || $file_ext == "xlsx" || $file_ext == "pptx")
        {
            if($file_ext == "doc") {
                return $this->read_doc();
            } elseif($file_ext == "docx") {
                return $this->read_docx();
            } elseif($file_ext == "xlsx") {
                return $this->xlsx_to_text();
            }elseif($file_ext == "pptx") {
                return $this->pptx_to_text();
            }
        } else {
            return "Invalid File Type";
        }
    }

}
```

The sample output is just like a text with no spacing, no indention, no heading and more.
This is a sample output that comes when I convert it successfully.

> ENTOURAGE LIST Officiating Pastor Pastor Ron EgeGroom’s Parents Mr. Mario Cabunoc Jr.Mrs. Susana CabunocBride’s Parents: Mr. Edilberto Marucut (Deceased)Mrs. Yolanda MarucutPrincipal Sponsors: Capt. Nemesio Desales III Mr. Edwin GinesMr. Valentino CabunocMr. Felipe MarucutMr. Nilo CabunocMr. Froilan Dulce Mr. Jose Fabie CabunocMr. Ramon Navarro Mr. Alfonso Fernandez Mr. Isagani CabunocMr. Allan CabunocMr. Julius OrpillaMrs. Rhodora DesalesMrs. Clarita Alonzo Mrs. Niña CabunocMrs. Robelita Ana Mrs. Marife CabunocMrs. Juvy Dulce Mrs. Imelda de GuiaMs. Imelda FuraggananMrs. Madamoiselle Granada Mrs. Mayeth Hidalgo Mrs. Analyn Cabida Mrs. Luz Ignacio Best Man Mario Cabunoc III Maid of Honor Marivic MarucutGroomsman Warren Van CabunocBridesmaid Cristhel Joy CabunocSecondary Sponsors Candles Christian Paulo DivinaAlanis Joyce AlbisoVeil Vincent Allen FernandezShiela May CabunocCord Kurt Jayson AlbisoCyrille Allyssa LimpinCoin Bearer Achilles Ronil Rain FacunlaBible Bearer Ralph Jacob Dulce Ring Bearer Caleb Joshua MarucutFlowergirlsShekinah Irish CabunocYurie Ysabelle MarucutElisha Bernice Cajandig

This text below is format I want to do just like in the docx file.

> ENTOURAGE LIST
>
> Officiating Pastor
>   Pastor Ron Ege
>
> Groom’s Parents
>   Mr. Mario Cabunoc Jr.     Mrs. Susana Cabunoc
>   Bride’s Parents:
>   Mr. Edilberto Marucut (Deceased)  Mrs. Yolanda Marucut
>
> Principal Sponsors:
>
> Capt. Nemesio Desales III
>   Mr. Edwin Gines
>   Mr. Valentino Cabunoc
>   Mr. Felipe Marucut
>   Mr. Nilo Cabunoc
>   Mr. Froilan Dulce
>   Mr. Jose Fabie Cabunoc
>   Mr. Ramon Navarro
>   Mr. Alfonso Fernandez
>   Mr. Isagani Cabunoc
>   Mr. Allan Cabunoc
>   Mr. Julius Orpilla
>   Mrs. Rhodora Desales
>   Mrs. Clarita Alonzo
>   Mrs. Niña Cabunoc
>   Mrs. Robelita Ana
>   Mrs. Marife Cabunoc
>   Mrs. Juvy Dulce
>   Mrs. Imelda de Guia
>   Ms. Imelda Furagganan
>   Mrs. Madamoiselle Granada
>   Mrs. Mayeth Hidalgo
>   Mrs. Analyn Cabida
>    Mrs. Luz Ignacio

I want to edit the format ouput of the docx file in php. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte The expected output I want is to format just like the same in the docx file. Im gonna edit it.

Comment: A plain text file can hardly be formatted the same as a Word document. There's a reason Word was developed: because text editing is no better than using a typewriter (if you even know what that is...). The only formatting you can do in plain text is to modfiy the amount of white space.

Comment: why don't you use phpword?

Comment: @Robert I can't deeply understand how to use phpword it's so complicated even if i search it there's always error in my code. Can you teach me easily how to use PHPWORD?

Comment: start using it, if you have problems search through web if you don't find solution post a question here. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
$striped_content = strip_tags($content);
```

removes all *p* and *br*

You need to protect them first, and then replace

```
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "#BR#", $content);
$content = str_replace('<w:br/>', "#BR#", $content);
$content = str_replace('<w:jc w:val="center"/>', "#BR##BR#", $content);
$content = str_replace('<w:jc w:val="both"/>', "#BR##BR#", $content);
$content = str_replace('<w:jc w:val="left"/>', "#BR##BR#", $content);
$content = str_replace('<w:jc w:val="right"/>', "#BR##BR#", $content);
$striped_content = strip_tags($content);
$striped_content = str_replace("#BR#","\r\n", $striped_content);
```

I use separated replace for each kind of paragraph because you also may want
to replace *"<w:jc w:val="center"/>"* with something like *"#CENTER#"* and then replace it with extra spaces. How I did.
If no, better join them in one.